# How to specify the parent POM to a submodule of a project?

Tags: maven

There is a Spring project having modules in it :

[image]

The `pom.xml` of the project has a parent :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bni.wfcredit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bni-wfcredit-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>bni-wfcredit-root</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>bni-wfcredit</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Bni wfcredit</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <modules>
        <module>bni-wfcredit-root</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

As you can see there is the parent tag pointing to the module bni-wfcredit-root.

**pom.xml of the bni-wfcredit-root module :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bni.wfcredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>bni-wfcredit-root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Bni wfcredit root</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-common</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-applogging</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-checklist</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-instruction</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-messaging</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-organisation</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-security</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-workflow</module>
        <module>../bni-wfcredit-mainapp</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        ...
    </build>
</project>
```

When I execute : `mvn -X clean install` at the directory D:\Projets\bni-wfcredit then I get error :

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 8 projects -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 5, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in JasperReports (http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third                                                                                      -party-ce-artifacts/) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 7, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 7, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit instead of com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root, please verify your project structure @ line 7, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:637)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:586)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:229)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Projets\bni-wfcredit\bni-wfcredit-common\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 1                                                                                      3 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:411)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:380)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:496)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:380)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:496)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:380)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:637)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:586)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:229)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:155)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.bni.wfcredit:bni-wfcredit-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:449)
        ... 29 more
```

So how to specify the parent ?

Answer (score 1):

The multi module structure should be like--

```
parent
├── pom.xml
├── module
    ├── pom.xml
```

First, check is the parent project in your local repository? If not then you need to check it out and build it yourself.

You need to add an empty `<relativePath>` to `<parent>` so that it resolves the parent pom from the repositories.

```
<parent>
   <groupId>com.bni.wfcredit</groupId>
   <artifactId>bni-wfcredit-root</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

You can read it more details [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent)  .

Comment: My case is not as usual : the parent is not as you mention but it is a module under the main project ! So how to point to the module `bni-wfcredit-root` from the outer pom ?

Comment: Based on the given structure the relativePath should not be defined cause the default is `../pom.xml`...!

Answer (score 1):

Ok , I found the solution ( thank you guys for your answers ) : I set the relativepath of the main project to : `<relativePath>bni-wfcredit-root/pom.xml</relativePath>` and I set the relativepath of the other modules to `<relativePath>../bni-wfcredit-root/pom.xml</relativePath>` ( except for the root module :) )

Answer (score 0):

The parent pom is loaded at compile time from the configured maven repository. Is not the one on the root project, neither the one in the module.

To install the parent pom locally you need to run on the parent pom project the command:

> mvn install

or, if you already have the parent pom project jar

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-file

for more info refer to the [maven repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) and [mvn install command](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) (How do I create a JAR and install it in my local repository?)